# Jquery Countdown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I have following countdown code.

```
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date(2016 , 0, 12, 12);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay, layout: '{dn} {dl}, {hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, and {sn} {sl}'});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
```

I just want to change the counter to extend one year, i changed the year from 2015 to 2016 but it is not working My landing page is hosted [Here](http://landbuster.com). Appreciate any help

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: it seems that the div with id=year doesn't exists in your page.

Comment: yes. I noticed that too. but the timer issue is still there how can i change this timer year. It is standard jquery coundown.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i am not familiar with countdown.js but here is an pure javascript solution.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer()
}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var dateThen = new Date(2016 , 11, 0, 12);
    var dateNow = new Date();
    var diff = dateThen - dateNow;

    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((diff - (days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((diff - (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60) - (days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((diff - (minutes * 1000 * 60) - (hours * 1000 * 60 * 60) - (days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 1000);
    
    document.querySelector('[data-days]').innerHTML = days;
    document.querySelector('[data-hours]').innerHTML = hours;
    document.querySelector('[data-minutes]').innerHTML = minutes;
    document.querySelector('[data-seconds]').innerHTML = seconds;
}
```

```css
#defaultCountdown {
    background-color: #232323;
    width: 757px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.hasCountdown {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #E5E5E5;
    margin-top: 45px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="defaultCountdown" class="hasCountdown">
    <span data-days></span>,
    <span data-hours></span>,
    <span data-minutes></span>,
    <span data-seconds></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the date you are setting is already passed.

```
new Date(2016 , 0, 12, 12)
```

means 12th of January.

Perhaps you want `new Date(2016 , 11, 0, 12)`

Answer (score 0):

The date you have inserted

```
new Date(2016 , 0, 12, 12);
```

is already passed

```
Date {Tue Jan 12 2016 12:00:00}
```